# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF)

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax-error

I think Iam getting blind...

I really dont find the syntax error in my code

```
<?php if (!is_page(array('865'))); ?>
    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Where is my mistake?!

best regards

Comment: `<?php if (!is_page(array('865'))): ?>`

Answer (score 3):

There must be a colon instead of a semicolon...

```
<?php if (!is_page(array('865'))): ?>
    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```